# Tolerances in Numerical quadrature - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods

What is the difference between `abtol` and `reltol` in MATLAB when performing numerical quadrature?

I have an triple integral that is supposed to generate a number between 0 and 1 and I am wondering what would be the best tolerance for my application?

Any other ideas on decreasing the time of `integral3` execution.

Also does anyone know whether `integral3` or `quadgk` is faster?

Comment: This isn't specifically about numeric quadrature, but you might find [this discussion at MatlabCentral](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/26743-absolute-and-relative-tolerance-definitions) helpful.

Comment: Have you tried benchmarking the two options for your specific application on your platform? It seems like you might try comparing `integral` too since you're already using `quadgk` for a triple integral. There's also the deprecated `triplequad`.

Comment: this question is related to my other question which I posted yesterday and you asked me to edit it.. I used integral3 and it is taking forever to compute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When performing the integration, MATLAB (or most any other integration software) computes a low-order solution `qLow` and a high-order solution `qHigh`.

There are a number of different methods of computing the *true error* (i.e., how far either `qLow` or `qHigh` is from the actual solution `qTrue`), but MATLAB simply computes an *absolute error* as the difference between the high and low order integral solutions:

```
errAbs = abs(qLow - qHigh).
```

If the integral is truly a large value, that difference may be large in an absolute sense but not a relative sense.  For example, `errAbs` might be `1E3`, but `qTrue` is `1E12`; in that case, the method could be said to converge relatively since at least 8 digits of accuracy has been reached.
So MATLAB also considers the *relative error* :

```
errRel = abs(qLow - qHigh)/abs(qHigh).
```

You'll notice I'm treating `qHigh` as `qTrue` since it is our best estimate.

Over a given sub-region, if the error estimate falls below either the absolute limit or the relative limit times the current integral estimate, the integral is considered converged.  If not, the region is divided, and the calculation repeated.

For the `integral` function and `integral2`/`integral3` functions with the iterated method, the low-high solutions are a [Gauss-Kronrod](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Kronrod_quadrature_formula) 7-15 pair (the same 7-th order/15-th order set used by `quadgk`.
For the `integral2`/`integral3` functions with the tiled method, the low-high solutions are a Gauss-Kronrod 3-7 pair (I've never used this option, so I'm not sure how it compares to others).

Since all of these methods come down to a Gauss-Kronrod quadrature rule, I'd say sticking with `integral3` and letting it do the adaptive refinement as needed is the best course.

Comment: `integral`, `integral2`, and `integral3` are also much more likely to see improvements and performance optimizations in future Matlab versions.

Comment: @troyHaskin are you suggesting that I use the integral3 and modify the method to being iterated?

Comment: also how can make integral3 do adaptive refinement?

Comment: @George I would go with iterated due to the higher-order of the rule, but I'm not sure if the tiled method is faster or more accurate on-average due to my lacking of experience.  All of the methods used adaptive refinement, interval splitting, to achieve convergence.

Comment: thanks, so for example for my application, i know that the number should fall of between 0 and 1, should I be using for my triple integral, abstol or reltol, also what would you suggest as a good number 1e-30?@TroyHaskin

Comment: @George Either should work in your case since you values are small (i.e., less than one), but they have different meanings:  `AbsTol = 1E-8` says your answer is estimated to be about 8 decimals places accurate while `RelTol = 1E-8` says it is accurate to within ~0.000001%.  I tend to favor absolute rather than relative tolerance when things are scaled about 1.  But keep in mind that differences below ~`2E-16` will be generally be `0` due to floating point accuracy.